# 3D visualisation and simulation in a browser?

Tags: javascript, animation, 3d, visualization, simulation

I'm looking for framework to develop a simple 3D simulation and visualisation JavaScript app.

Basically I need to set up a few parameters, and then hit start and see the particle flying in 3D.

I don't have much experience with any JS framework, but I can learn one for this. I read something about D3.js and AngularJS, and it seems like MVC is a must.

I saw bokeh, mpld3 and a demos of few other frameworks: but none seems to facilitate visualisation of simulation: all I saw were focused on visualising and facilitating to read static data.

Answer (score 1):

For 3D animation in the browser today you are going to want to use WebGL. I personally enjoy using the [Three.js library](http://threejs.org/). Three.js is also very popular and has loads of tutorials.